# Using Regex to split string in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have string like that in the ".ini" file:

```
DateTimeFormat={"MMM dd hh:mm:ss","dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss","yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss:mm.fff","MMM, dd yyyy"}
DateTime contain any posible format datetime we have.
```

Or as C# string:

```
string DateTimeFormat= "{\"MMM dd hh:mm:ss\",\"dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss\",\"yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss:mm.fff\"}";
```

I want to split string as result:

```
string[] result = {"MMM dd hh:mm:ss","dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss","yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss:mm.fff"}
```

How can I split using Regex in C# (I want to split with begin " and " end)

Comment: string and result are same ? , how do you want to split?

Comment: its not the same, in his C# code, that "string" is broken into and array of 3 parts

Comment: In txt file I have:
DateTimeFormat={"MMM dd hh:mm:ss","dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss","yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss:mm.fff"}.
And I want to split this string to string[].

Comment: can you paste actual data in the question

Comment: so far what you have shown doesn't need a regex

Comment: remove { and } using substring, and yeah use string.Split. or hmm... replace { and } with [ and ], and then run it via JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to List<string>

Comment: if I used string.Split, the string[0] = "{". and string[lenght-1]="}". and I don't want like that.

Comment: The reasson i want to use regex is to make code clean and look simple

Comment: So, I want to split string with begin " and end ". How can I do?

Comment: I have an answer with a simple way to do it with split.

Comment: @thehiep8x - I've never seen regex make code clean and simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use match instead of split, and `LINQ` to get all captured groups in an array (add `System.Xml.Linq` and `System.Linq` to your `using` statements):

```
var DateTimeFormat = "{\"MMM dd hh:mm:ss\",\"dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss\",\"yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss:mm.fff\"}";
var matches = Regex.Matches(DateTimeFormat, @"""([^""]+)""");
var res42 = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
```

The `"([^"]+)"` regex assumes you have no escaped double quotation marks in the quoted values. If you need to account for escaped quotes, you can use `(?<!\\)"(.+?)(?<!\\)"` regex (`@"(?<!\\)""(.+?)(?<!\\)"""`). But I do not believe it is the case here.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

to split it on the comma and get rid of the {} and "

```
s.Split(new [] { ',', '{', '}', '"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

or with Regex and a bit of Linq using the same technique

```
Regex.Split(s, "[,\"{}]").Where(e => e.Length >0).ToArray()
```

Comment: A bit safer would be `s.Trim('{', '}').Split(',')` because it doesn't remove `{` and `}` within the text, but only at the start and end of the string.

Comment: seperate question but try using capital H for 24 hour clock

Comment: if in txt file I have : 
DateTimeFormat={"MMM dd hh:mm:ss","dd/MMM/yyyy:H:mm:ss","yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss:mm.fff","MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm","MMM, dd yyyy"}. Your code is incorrect because "MMM, dd yyyy". So I want split with begin" and " end.

Comment: @thehiep8x: If you are not satisfied with the code, why did you accept the answer? And please update the question if the input data is not what you originally posted.